# while mysql can create direcory in /var/lib which with permission drwxr-xr-x?

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

when I use mysql by docker and I find a problem:In mysql configure file my.cnf,I set as follows:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
user=Tim
...
```

But as you konw the permission of /var/lib is 755 which konw as drwxr-xr-x,only root user can create file in this directory.But why can mysql create file in /var/lib with user Tim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The startup script still runs as Linux `root`, then switches:

> Run the mysqld server as the user having the name user_name or the
>   numeric user ID user_id. (“User” in this context refers to a system
>   login account, not a MySQL user listed in the grant tables.)
>
> **This option is mandatory when starting mysqld as root. The server changes its user ID during its startup sequence, causing it to run as
>   that particular user rather than as root.**

Taken from [`--user` documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_user).